# Block Cookie from AJAX REST call in Javascript

Tags: jquery, mobile, cookies, angularjs, weblogic

We are building a mobile app based on webtech. Our endpoint (weblogic 11g) sends a jessionid cookie as well as a _wl_authcookie_jessionid_ cookie which is later automatically sent to the server again for authorization purposes. But we dont want this to happen, rather we want to ask the user to enter his credentials at the start of the app, then store these credentials within javascript runtime variables and, if the user clicks logout, we toss those variables. But then if one enters arbitrary login credentials, the ajax request attaches the cookies to the request and the server ignores our BASIC header and instead uses the former cookies to authorize the user.

So how do we either: delete the cookies, or block them from being placed in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

The probable solution that I can think of would involve:

1) Disable session cookie that WLS automatically sets for the application (which has the endpoints that your mobile app access). This can be done by setting following in weblogic.xml:

```
...
<session-descriptor>
    <cookies-enabled>false</cookies-enabled>
</session-descriptor>
...
```

2) set "enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials" to false (note it affects whole domain)

```
How: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e13711/thin_client.htm#autoId8
```

3) create servlet filter in your server side application that will act as authenticator/authorizer for incoming requests.